# Executar função no app android quando um botão em uma página web for pressionado

Tags: java, android-studio, aplicação-web

tenho um app (desenvolvido no android studio) que obtém dados do acelerômetro. Agora preciso fazer uma página web com um botão, quando o botão da página web for clicado, os dados do acelerômetro que já tenho em uma variável, serão exibidos na página web. Preciso de dicas de como posso implementar a parte web e a parte de escuta do app android. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Só conheço um método usando Javascript Interface, porém essa interface só se comunica com  `webView`, caso queira dar uma olhada tem o link do google https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java

Comment: Bruno, obrigado pela resposta. Acho que me expressei errado. A parte da WEB não rodará dentro do app android.

Comment: Olha acho que você vai ter que criar uma api.

Comment: Vai ter que criar uma api sim, com json vai ficar mais fácil para adaptar a linguagem do app, mais porque você não fez um app hibrido? seria mais fácil lidar com essas coisas e você poderia ir na onda dos "apps lite e apps go". Se você quer uma sugestão alternativa a api, utilize um pwa na web e link ele no aplicativo com webview, eu não consigo testar aqui, pois o meu pc não aguenta o visual studio e o android studio juntos, então não vou mostrar como se faz, mais alguém deve saber como fazer. *O pwa permitirá que as coisas funcionem sem internet então use pwa e não uma pagina da web simples,

Answer (score 0):

Quando você quer integrar web e app. Use uma api. Para construir api em php tem laravel, slim framework e tem muitos outros framework que você pode usar.